# Managed package existing data lost while upgrading package?

Tags: apex

one of our client lost his package data when they upgrade version of managed package. How can i reproduce this issue at my end or there is any solution to fix it.

Comment: The only way that would have happened is if they uninstalled first or you had a post install script go wrong. Or they are simply mistaken.

Comment: They are losing only one object data.

Comment: It just simply does not happen. Yours would be the first I have heard of it if true. Have you seen it with your own eyes? I would not take clients word for it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions to ask to find out exactly what happened:

- What data has been lost?
- Is it all records of a single Object?
- More than one object?
- Standard object data?
- Data in custom fields on standard objects?
- What was in the package upgrade?
- Did your new package delete any objects or custom fields from the previous packages?
- How old is the version they upgraded from?
- How old is the version they upgraded to?

Knowing exactly what has been lost will help you (and us) understand what might have happened. That's your first step.

Salesforce work hard to preserve data in a customer's org when a package is upgraded. That's why they restrict what you can remove from your package once it's been added and, I guess, one of the reasons why they don't allow you to roll back to a previous version of a package.

Even if you delete an object from your package, Salesforce will still [leave the object in the customer's org in an unmanaged state](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components) (the customer can delete the object and all records themselves if they want to).

Having said that, sometimes errors happen. I've seen a case where a package upgrade in which we removed an object left the object in a corrupted state in the org.

As @Eric has mentioned in a comment, you could have a post install script going wrong, as well.

I would suggest raising a ticket with Salesforce, as this is not supposed to happen. Your clients would have to raise it, as it happened in their org. I don't think you can raise it on their behalf.